# Unable to start docker terminal

Tags: docker, settings

yesterday I just installed docker to my win 7 using docker toolbox... i refereed to some installation tutorials and successfully did it.. but now when I start docker terminal I'm getting following error.. I went through the websites but I'm unable to find solution,i have gone through many website for this question, they are teaching how to install it which I have done with same procedure [Have I done any mistake in setting up of docker..??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EsEj.jpg)
 can anyone guide me for the same.. I'm new to docker... thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

if your installing with boot2docker place the boot2doker.iso in cache i.e c:/username/.docker/machine/cache and re-run in terminal